# Why does transfering data from one Activity to another doesnt work inside a query in firebasefirestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to pass values of filtered chips that a user has selected in order to retrieve only the required shops he want in that particular criteria.

now i created everything and the data i am getting after finishing from my FilterActivity is being passed into my HomeActivity. but this data is not being 'read' or 'accepted' inside my query since it doesn't produce the correct output. When i use a static value inside the query it would work. now i need it to be a changing value depending on what the use has selected.

This is inside my HomeActivity that opens the Filter Activity:

```
  filterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,FilterActivity.class);
               startActivityForResult(intent,101);
            }
        });
```

this is my FilterActivity with a few examples:

```
 private Chip rate2,rate3,rate4;
private ArrayList<String> selectedChipData;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
        rate2 = findViewById(R.id.chip_Rate_2);

 selectedChipData = new ArrayList<>();
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    selectedChipData.add(compoundButton.getText().toString().trim());
                }else{
                    selectedChipData.remove(compoundButton.getText().toString().trim());
                }

            }
        };

 rate2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);



}
```

and this is the button the user clicks when he wants to apply one of the filter options:

```
filter_reset = findViewById(R.id.filter_reset);
        filter_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("data",selectedChipData.toString().trim());
                setResult(101,resultIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

now in my HomeActivity i created the onActivityResult:

```
String Data;
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==101){
            Data = data.getStringExtra("data");
            Log.d("TAG", data.getStringExtra("data"));
            Query q = firebaseFirestore.collection("Shops").whereEqualTo("location",Data);
}
}


Query q = firebaseFirestore.collection("Shops").whereEqualTo("location",Data);
// this is my query and how i am trying to pass the matched users selected chip to the location of the Shops table.
```

What am i missing or doing wrong inside my query and how to fix it? can someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

Did by any chance you forget to tell intent to go back to Home Page

```
filter_reset = findViewById(R.id.filter_reset);
        filter_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(FilterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 // Changed the above Intent Paras
                resultIntent.putExtra("data",selectedChipData.toString().trim());
                setResult(101,resultIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: i just tried this and it still didn't work. i dont think it changes anything because as i said when i put a static value it would return the output i require and what is expected.

Comment: Ohh Sorry , I might have overlooked the Static part or understood it wrong. I had this problem and this corrected that. Let me see further what else might be giving the problem

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem, it wasn't matching with my database because the value is an array and has [] in the result. if i put the [] in my database it works fine.